# Sinon spy function called but not tracked

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I am using Mocha and sinon to spy on a function call. The function is called correctly but the spy is not tracking it.

Here is the module i am testing

```
export default (() => {

  function test1(){
      console.log('called second func');
      return 5;
  }

  function callThis(){
      console.log('called first func');
      test1();
  }

  return {
      test1,
      callThis
  };

})();
```

and here is the test

```
import Common from './common';

describe('spy test', () => {
  var setSpy = sinon.spy(Common, 'test1');

  Common.callThis();

  var result = setSpy.called;

  it(`does the test`, () => {
      expect(result).to.equal(true);
  });

});
```

I am basically calling the first function but want to check the second function is called as a result. The console logs tell me this is happening, but the spy returns false and does not notice the thing it is spying on. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `sinon.spy(Common, 'test1');` you are modifying the `test1` field on the `Common` object to replace it with a spy. However, the code you have in `common.js` is calling `test1` *directly* instead of calling `test1` *through the object that your module exports.* Therefore, when you do `Common.callThis()`, the spy is not touched, and you get the error you observed.

Here's a modified `common.js` file that would allow your test to pass:

```
export default (() => {

  var obj = {};

  obj.test1 = function test1(){
      console.log('called second func');
      return 5;
  }

  obj.callThis = function callThis(){
      console.log('called first func');
      // This calls `test1` through `obj` instead of calling it directly.
      obj.test1();
  }

  return obj;
})();
```