# How to use sinon.stub with ava?

Tags: testing, sinon, ava

Any suggestion how to use `Sinon` with `ava` ?
when I run `ava`, `stub.called` is always `false`

target.js

```
const foo = () => { bar() }
const bar = () => { }

module.exports = { foo, bar }
```

target.test.js

```
import test from 'ava';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as target from './target';

test('foo', t=>{
    const stub = sinon.stub(target, 'bar')    
    target.foo();
    t.true(stub.called)
})
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732572/sinon-spy-function-called-but-not-tracked